# Example code calls a Application DbContext 1st before I can fill the data. Advice how to change

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I need help from one of you Wizzard... I have bought an example shopping chart payment program that works but it has a hardcoded and calls an ApplicationDb context FIRST before load it with data from the cart. it works hardcoded.
How can I call it after the Index function is called so I can load it with data?
I believe for the rest of the example code to work it needs to create this Application context or it will not work. I'll have to try it.
Here is the code... OrderRequest is called before anything else. I need to load the data before it is called and I'm lost.

namespace MyCard.Controllers
{

```
    public OrderRequest orderRequest = new OrderRequest()
    {
        CheckoutPaymentIntent = "CAPTURE",

        ApplicationContext = new ApplicationContext
        {
            BrandName = "PRA",
            LandingPage = "BILLING",
            CancelUrl = "https://www.pra.org/PayPal/Cancel",
            ReturnUrl = "https://www.pra.org/PayPal/Success",
            UserAction = "CONTINUE",
            ShippingPreference = "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS"
        },
        PurchaseUnits = new List<PurchaseUnitRequest>()
            {
                new PurchaseUnitRequest{
                    ReferenceId =  _Cart.Id.ToString(),// "ReferenceId1",
                    Description = _P.FullName, // "Description1",
                    CustomId = _Cart.Bid.ToString(), // "CustomId1",
                    SoftDescriptor = "OnlineSale", // "SoftDescriptor1",
                    AmountWithBreakdown = new AmountWithBreakdown
                    {

                        CurrencyCode = _Currency,
                        Value = _Cart.TotalDue.ToString(), // "110.00",
                        AmountBreakdown = new AmountBreakdown
                        {
                            ItemTotal = new Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = _Currency,
                                Value = _Cart.SubTotal.ToString()// "90.00"
                            },
                            Shipping = new Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = _Currency,
                                Value = _Cart.Freight.ToString()// "15.00"
                            },
                            Handling = new Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = _Currency,
                                Value = _Cart.Handling.ToString()// "5.00"
                            },
                            TaxTotal = new Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = _Currency,
                                Value = _Cart.TaxAmt.ToString(), //"10.00"
                            },
                            ShippingDiscount = new Money
                            {
                                CurrencyCode = _Currency,
                                Value = _Cart.Discount.ToString() // "10.00"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    Items =  _CartItems, //List<Item>
                    //{

                    //    new Item
                    //    {
                    //        Name = "Product 1",
                    //        Description = "Product 1 Description",
                    //        Sku = "Sku1",
                    //        UnitAmount = new Money
                    //        {
                    //            CurrencyCode = _Currency,
                    //            Value = "90.00"
                    //        },
                    //        Tax = new Money
                    //        {
                    //            CurrencyCode = _Currency,
                    //            Value = "10.00"
                    //        },
                    //        Quantity = "1",
                    //        Category = "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
                    //    },
                    //},
                    ShippingDetail = new ShippingDetail
                    {
                        Name = new Name
                        {
                            FullName = _ckOut.FullName
                        },
                        AddressPortable = new AddressPortable
                        {
                            AddressLine1 = _ckOut.BilAddLine1,
                            AdminArea2 = "",
                            AdminArea1 = "",
                            PostalCode = _ckOut.BilZip,
                            CountryCode = _ckOut.BilCountry
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    };
```

}